# ResourceManager falls back to default resources instead of reading from satellite assembly

Tags: c#, localization, satellite-assembly, resourcemanager

I've the following folder structure for three projects:

```
MyClassLibrary1
  Class1.cs
  Resources\
      en-GB\
          Strings.en-GB.txt
      Strings.resx
          Strings.designer.cs (auto-generated)
MyClassLibrary2 (references MyClassLibrary1)
    Class1.cs
MyAppExe (references MyClassLibrary1 and MyClassLibrary2)
    Program.cs
```

Under MyClassLibrary1 project:

```
In Strings.resx, I've string resources defined, let's say:
    <data name="SchoolString"><value>Preschool</value></data>
In Strings.en-GB.txt, I have:
    SchoolString=Playgroup
```

MyClassLibrary1's Project properties -> Pre-Build, I've the following:

```
CD $(ProjectDir)Resources
FOR /D %%1 IN (*) DO (
    CD "%%1"
    resgen.exe "Strings.%%1.txt"
    if %errorlevel% 0 al.exe /t:lib /culture:"%%1" /embed:"Strings.%%1.resources" /out:MyClassLibrary1.resources.dll
    if not exist "$(TargetDir)%%1" md "$(TargetDir)%%1"
    move /Y "MyClassLibrary1.resources.dll" "$(TargetDir)%%1"
    CD ..
)
```

Under MyAppExe project, in Program.cs:

```cs
static void Main() {
    Strings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    Trace.WriteLine(Strings.SchoolString);
}
```

The problem is that the ResourceManager, for some reason, keeps on falling back to the default resource file (embedded in MyAppExe). Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

The output I keep getting no matter what I try is "Preschool" instead of "Playgroup". It's like the satellite assembly is not being resolved at all.

Comment: A satellite assembly must be present in a sub-directory of the EXE directory that has the same name as the culture.  A directory named "en-GB" in your case.  It doesn't look like your build event takes care of this.

Comment: Actually it does, it goes to bin\Debug\en-GB\ folder

Comment: @hans-passant: Just came across this KB article - [KB839861](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839861) - I guess I have to change to `resgen.exe "Strings.%%1.txt" "MyClassLibrary1.Resources.Strings.%%1.txt"` and also change to `al.exe /t:lib /embed:"MyClassLibrary1.Resources.Strings.%%1.resources" /out:"MyClassLibrary1.resources.dll"` for al.exe to generate the correct namespace name. I will try it tonight and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the correct procedure provided under http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839861, the application is working as expected now.

All I had to do was to change the "Pre-build event command line" as follows:

`CD "$(ProjectDir)Resources"

FOR /D %%1 IN (*) DO (

    CD "%%1"

    resgen.exe "Strings.%%1.txt" "MyClassLibrary1.Resources.Strings.%%1.resources"
    if %errorlevel% == 0 (

        al.exe /t:lib /embed:"MyClassLibrary1.Resources.Strings.%%1.resources" /culture:"%%1" /out:MyClassLibrary1.resources.dll

        if not exist "$(TargetDir)%%1" md "$(TargetDir)%%1"

        move /Y "MyClassLibrary1.resources.dll" "$(TargetDir)%%1"

    )

    CD ..

)`

Hope it helps someone.